# Getting dwa 123 Dlink wireless usb adapter working

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb-modem

I compiled the source code and inserted the USB device, according to this blogs instruction: [Install DWA-125 wireless driver on Ubuntu 11.10](http://kaustavdm.in/2011/10/install-dwa-125-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-11-10.html)

When I do a lsmod:

```
lsmod | grep rt
rt5370sta              726167  0
```

However iwconfig gives:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Could someone please tell me what to do so that I can get the USB adapter running fine.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem? I just ran into it and could use some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following code in the console

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
```

remove previously manual installed modules
 **eg:- sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu**

```
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Unplug , re-plug you should get going.

**Tested on Dlink DWA-123  rev D1**
Speedtest results : http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3477686124

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.